# Should I generalize this question

Tags: discussion, editing

I asked this question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/18165/7753) yesterday and today I realized that the first answer I received was general enough that it could apply to any similar question with a different game and that really my question could easily be generalized so that other people looking for the same answer with a different game could find it.  So my question to meta is: Should I change my question to be more general and point others to potential answer (still trying to verify if this solves my issue) or leave it with "Portal" in the title and tags?

Thanks for your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you feel the question can be made more general without changing the answers, then by all means please do! Usually just making the title more generic is enough.

That said I'm not sure how exactly the question you asked can be expanded really...

Comment: Currently my question seems to focus just on the fact that the achievement shows up in Portal but not on Xbox Live - if Matthew Read's suggestion works (which seems like it should) it can be applied to any game this achievement issue applies to. For example if the same thing happened someone else but with Fallout 3 instead. So I'm thinking that I should remove the Portal tag and any references to Portal so that someone else wouldn't ask the same question about another game. I have just joined the community so I wanted to check before I made that change. Thanks :)